# Finding the source root directory in CMake for ROS

Tags: cmake, ros

Using CMake with ROS, one can end up with a directory tree like this:

```
+src
  -CMakeLists.txt (symbolic link to toplevel.cmake)
  -CMakeExtras.txt (I want to use this)
  +computing
    +perception
      +per1
        -CMakeLists.txt
      +per2
        -CMakeLists.txt
    +detection
      +det1
        -CMakeLists.txt
  +sensing
    +dev1
      -CMakeLists.txt
```

In the `CMakeExtras.txt` I want to set up CMake variable, load common packages just once, etc like for example:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -Wall ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
```

How can I do this? The `INCLUDE()` command is obvious, but I cannot edit the root level `CMakeLists.txt` and there doesn't seem to be a variable that will allow something like `INCLUDE("${OVERALL_SRC_DIR}/CMakeExtras.txt)`. I suppose:

```
catkin_make -DOVERALL_SRC_DIR=~/project/src
```

Would be one solution, but is there a neater way?

Comment: Not very familiar with ROS, so your question sounds a bit unclear to me. Where would you like to put the `include(${OVERALL_SRC_DIR}/CMakeExtras.txt)` if you can't edit the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`? Or you can?

Comment: I could live with manually putting into every other `CMakeLists.txt`, even though I have 107 of the things; I want to avoid having to tailor the path for every file, though. Writing a custom rule might also be another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: the question is still a bit unclear to me, so apologies in advance if the answer does not reflect your needs.

If the problem you want to solve is that you have a lot of directories like `src` in which the same top-level `CMakeLists.txt` is linked and you want to include a specific `CMakeExtras.txt` that resides in each particular directory, then you can solve this by adding:

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeExtras.txt)
```

to your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`. According to [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html):

> This the full path to the source directory that is currently being processed by cmake

and should solve this issue (i.e. the variable refers to the directory being processed, not to the `CMakeLists.txt` where it is used).

If instead your issue is how to compute the `src` path, given that a link to the top level `CMakelists.txt` is there, then you simply want to use [PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) which:

> is the source directory of the most recent project() command.